# HEAD is now at b22354c Fix validation, add allowBlank and make sure to honor it

Tags: git

I was trying:

```
git reset --hard
```

But I am getting

> HEAD is now at b22354c Fix validation, add allowBlank and make sure to honor it

Can anybody help me regarding that? What does it mean and what should I do?

Comment: i don't think it is as bad question that deserve Down vote, This is real problem I am neither  able to reset nor stash

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

HEAD just means the commit that's currently checked out.  `git reset --hard` means, "Take me back to the last commit I was on, and remove all changes from my working directory."  When you reset your HEAD to that commit, git was courteous enough to let you know that the operation succeeded.  In this case, that commit has a hash that begins with `b22354c` and the message "Fix validation, add allowBlank and make sure to honor it".  If you run `git log`, you will that commit at the top of the list, meaning it is the most recent one in history.  If you run `git status`, you will see that your working directory is clean--i.e. all changes since commit b22354c were reverted.

Comment: Thanks But it doesn't reset and i m still unable to switch the branch and for some reason i can't stash but i have to switch the branch, What can be solution ?

Comment: If you have untracked files, those won't be deleted with a git reset, then you have to do a `git clean -fd` (this will delete all untracked files and directories, so if you're not 100% sure, make a backup first).

Comment: And if you want to stash untracked changes, you have to execute `git stash -u`